# arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000840: The value is not a Data Element. Failed to execute (Copy)

Tags: arcpy, error-000840

Check this straightforward code that exports the subset of a shapefile (path_of_shp) using where_clause:

```
where_clause = '"new" = 1'
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(path_of_shp, "feature")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("feature", "NEW_SELECTION", where_clause)
arcpy.Copy_management("feature", "C:/GIS/output.shp")
```

This gives an error:

> arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not
>   valid. ERROR 000840: The value is not a Data Element. Failed to
>   execute (Copy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Copy Features tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/copy-features.htm) instead of the Copy tool.
The Copy tool wants physical items, not a "virtual" item like you get from Make Feature Layer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using four lines of code to do this, you could use just two:

```
where_clause = '"new" = 1'
arcpy.Select_analysis(path_of_shp, "C:/GIS/output.shp", where_clause)
```

or even just one (depending on whether you want your `where_clause` value to be re-used later in your code):

```
arcpy.Select_analysis(path_of_shp, "C:/GIS/output.shp", "new = 1")
```

Note that I simplified the where_clause in the one-liner because double-quotes around the field name have not been needed for quite a few versions.